# How to capitalize the first character of every sentence

Tags: c#

Create an application with a method that accepts a string as an argument and returns a copy of the string with the first character of each sentence capitalized.

This is what I have to far and I can't seem to get it right:

```
    //Create method to process string.
    private string Sentences(string input)
    {
        //Capitalize first letter of input.
        char firstLetter = char.ToUpper(input[0]);

        //Combine the capitalize letter with the rest of the input.
        input = firstLetter.ToString() + input.Substring(1);

        //Create a char array to hold all characters in input.
        char[] letters = new char[input.Length];

        //Read the characters from input into the array.
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            letters[i] = input[i];
        }

        //Loop through array to test for punctuation and capitalize a character 2 index away.
        for (int index = 0; index < letters.Length; index++)
        {
            if(char.IsPunctuation(letters[index]))
            {
                if (!((index + 2) >= letters.Length))
                {
                    char.ToUpper(letters[index+ 2]);
                }
            }
        }

        for(int ind = 0; ind < letters.Length; ind++)
        {
            input += letters[ind].ToString();
        }

        return input;
    }
```

Comment: "I can't seem to get it right." - some details would be useful. What is the problem with your code?

Comment: There is at least one conceptual issue I see with your algorithm. What if the next letter after punctuation is not two characters away? There could be two spaces after the punctuation or it could be new line characters.

Comment: This sounds like homework, do you have known parameters for sentence identification? Because that is hard. When I have had to do that I ship the text up to Microsoft Cognitive Services and let it split the sentences for me.

Comment: Yes this is a homework problem. lets say the input is a paragraph with many sentences. How do I make sure all the first letter of every sentence is capitalized. I tried breaking down the input and put the individual characters in a char[ ] array to hold all characters. Then I want to test each element if its a punctuation. Once I find the array that holds the punctuation then I want to upper case the letter that is 2 elements away from the punctuation because in between the punctuation and the start of a sentence is a white space.

Comment: You just need to step through the input string and keep track of the punctuation that marks the end of a sentence. If you find one, make the next non-white-space char upper case: For example: https://ideone.com/M7Njw4

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a regex to identify all the dots in your sentence. Get the match, make it upper case and replace it back in the original sentence, in the match index. I dont actually have any IDE in which try the code on .NET right now but i can write it in pseudocode for better understanding.

```
    String setence = "your.setence.goes.here";
    Regex rx = new Regex("/\..*?[A-Z]/");
    foreach (Match match in rx.Matches(sentence))
    {
        setence.remove(match.Index, 2).insert(match.Index, String.ToUpper(match.Value));
    }
```

Comment: .!? and whitespaces after them need to be in the rx :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Linq.Aggregate` n - see comments in code and code output for explanation how it work's.

This one will respect "Bla. blubb" as well - you need to check for whitespaces after ".?!"

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

internal class Program
{
    static string Capitalize(string oldSentence )
    {
        return

            // this will look at oldSentence char for char, we start with a
            // new string "" (the accumulator, short acc)
            // and inspect each char c of oldSentence

            // comment all the Console.Writelines in this function, thats 
            // just so you see whats done by Aggregate, not needed for it to 
            // work

            oldSentence 
            .Aggregate("", (acc, c) =>
             {
                 System.Console.WriteLine("Accumulated: " + acc);
                 System.Console.WriteLine("Cecking:     " + c);

                 // if the accumulator is empty or the last character of 
                 // trimmed acc is a ".?!" we append the
                 // upper case of c to it
                 if (acc.Length == 0 || ".?!".Any(p => p == acc.Trim().Last())) // (*)
                     acc += char.ToUpper(c);
                 else
                     acc += c; // else we add it unmodified

                 System.Console.WriteLine($"After:      {acc}\n");

                 return acc; // this returns the acc for the next iteration/next c                  
            });
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.SetBufferSize(120, 1000);
        var oldSentence = "This is a testSentence. some occurences "
            + "need capitalization! for examlpe here. or here? maybe "
            + "yes, maybe not.";

        var newSentence = Capitalize(oldSentence);

        Console.WriteLine(new string('*', 80));
        Console.WriteLine(newSentence);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**(*)**

- `".?!".Any(p => p == ... ))` means does the string `".?!"` contain any character that equals `...`
- `acc.Trim().Last()` means: remove whitespaces in front/on end of `acc` and give me the last character

`.Last()` and `.Any()` are also Linq. Most of the Linq-esc extension can be found here: **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx**

Output (snipped - its rather longish ;o)

```
Accumulated:
Cecking:     T
After:      T

Accumulated: T
Cecking:     h
After:      Th

Accumulated: Th
Cecking:     i
After:      Thi

Accumulated: Thi
Cecking:     s
After:      This

Accumulated: This
Cecking:
After:      This

Accumulated: This
Cecking:     i
After:      This i

Accumulated: This i
Cecking:     s
After:      This is

<snipp - .. you get the idea how Aggregate works ...>

Accumulated: This is a testSentence.
Cecking:     s
After:      This is a testSentence. S

<snipp>

Accumulated: This is a testSentence. Some occurences need capitalization!
Cecking:     f
After:      This is a testSentence. Some occurences need capitalization! F

<snipp> 
********************************************************************************
This is a testSentence. Some occurences need capitalization! For examlpe here. Or here? Maybe yes, maybe not.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two tasks:

1) Split text into sentences
2) Capitalize the first char in the sentences

Task one can be very complex, e.g. because there a lot of crazy languages out there. Put since this is homework I assume you can go ahead and simply split by well know separators.

Task two is just about basic string operations. You select the first char, make it uppercase and add the missing part of the sentence via a substring operation.

Here is a code example:

```
char[] separators = new char[] { '!', '.', '?' };
string[] sentencesArray = "First sentence. second sentence!lastone.".Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var i = 0;
Array.ForEach(sentencesArray, e =>
{
 sentencesArray[i] = e.Trim().First().ToString().ToUpper() + 
 e.Trim().Substring(1);
 i++;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have created a method in Groovy for the same

```
String capitalizeFirstCharInSentence(String str) {
    String result = ''
    str = str.toLowerCase()
    List<String> strings = str.tokenize('.')
    strings.each { line ->
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(line)
        int i = 0
        while (i < builder.size() - 1 && !Character.isLowerCase(builder.charAt(i))) {
            i++
        }
        if (Character.isLowerCase(builder.charAt(i))) {
            builder.setCharAt(i, builder.charAt(i).toUpperCase())
            result += builder.toString() + '.'
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the way you formatted your method because it made it easy for newer coders to read so I decided to try to make the code work while maintaining the structure.  The main problem I saw was that you were not replacing the arrays after formatting them.

```
//Create method to process string.
private string Sentences(string input)
{
    //Create a char array to hold all characters in input.
    char[] letters = new char[input.Length];

    //Read the characters from input into the array.
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        letters[i] = input[i];
    }

    //Capitalize first letter of input.
    letters[0] = char.ToUpper(letters[0]);

    //Loop through array to test for punctuation and capitalize a character 2 index away.
    for (int index = 0; index < letters.Length; index++)
    {
        if(char.IsPunctuation(letters[index]))
        {
            if (index + 2 <= letters.Length)
            {
                letters[index + 2] = char.ToUpper(letters[index+ 2]);
            }
        }
    }

    // convert array back to string
    string results = new string(letters)
    return results;
}
```